# Создание стартового окна-загрузки приложения Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, окно

Хочу создать окно загрузки приложения, до запуска главного потока программы, как сделать сроку, которая будет заполняться типо отображая загрузку.Я так понимаю данный stage должен быть запущен здесь:

```
   @Override

public void init(){

//Инициализация любых данных, до включения основного потока Start в работу.

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABGGDJG Тут информация про Preloader. https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098 Готовая реализация для splash screen

Comment: Спасибо за конкретный ответ